# Extract Content from eBay Using jQuery / Javascript

Tags: jquery

I'm normally able to easily extract content from websites using jQuery but I'm having trouble extract the some content from this page:

http://cgi.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=290585620456

I want to extract the product name, quantity available, and quantity sold in the following format:

2 pc 10" Bamboo Single Point Knitting Needles 0-11 - 32 sold
Size 0 - 5 available
Size 1 - 5 available
Size 2 - 5 available
...
Size 8 - Out of Stock

but I can't seem to figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just tried a simple jquery, and it is working:
$('h1').text()
returns:
"2 pc 10" Bamboo Single Point Knitting Needles 0-11"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to look at either [cross-domain jQuery AJAX guides](http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) <sub>(1)</sub>, or the [eBay API](https://www.x.com/developers/ebay/javascript-developer-center) <sub>(2)</sub>.

---

1. Once you scrape the details from eBay, you'll then have to parse them for just the info you want, which can be tedious.
2. Specifically for the API, you could take a look at `GetSingleItem` - http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/shopping/docs/callref/GetSingleItem.html

Comment: Oh yeah. I forgot eBay has an API. I'll just use that. Te cross-domain jQuery AJAX guide is pretty useful too! I didn't know you could do that. Thanks.